# Prove $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has no subgroup of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We are asked to prove that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has no subgroup of finite index. And think about $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with the same question. However, I think if there is a homomorphism $\varphi\colon\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to C = \left \{  1, -1\right \}$, which take matrix with positive determinant to 1 while matrix with negative determinant to -1, then the kernel is a subgroup with finite index. Am I wrong?

Comment: Real matrices can have determinant other than $\pm 1$

Comment: You are right. So the question is perhaps about the group of real matrices of positive determinant having no subgroup of finite index.

Comment: @user376902 I made a mistake. I wrongly denoted it as det. It is just homomorphism.

Comment: @RubiscoLee OK. You're right that $GL^+_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ of index $2$.

Comment: @ P Vanchinathan Yeah, maybe it is about real matrices of positive determinant having no subgroup of finite index. Can you give me hint about this question? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: First prove that $PGL(n,{\mathbb R})$, $n\ge 2$, is simple (as an abstract group). See section 3.2 of "A Course in the Theory of Groups" by D.Robinson. Now use this result to show that $GL_{+}(n,{\mathbb R})$ (the group of invertible matrices with positive determinant) has no proper finite index subgroups. An alternative: First show that the additive group ${\mathbb R}$ has no proper finite index subgroups. Then prove that $SL(n, {\mathbb R})$ is generated by the "elementary matrix subgroups" $E_{ij}$ (aka "root subgroups"), which are groups of matrices with $1$ on the diagonal, an arbitrary real number in the $a_{ij}$ slot and zero elsewhere, e.g.:
$$
E_{12}= \{\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1&x&0&...\\
0&1&0&...\\
0&0&1&...\\
\end{array}\right]: x\in {\mathbb R}\}.
$$ 
Use this to show that $GL_+(n,{\mathbb R})$ has no nontrivial homomorphisms to finite groups.